# Extract ruby hash element value from an array of objects

Tags: ruby

I've got the following array

```
[#<Attachment id: 73, container_id: 1, container_type: "Project", filename: "Eumna.zip", disk_filename: "140307233750_Eumna.zip", filesize: 235303, content_type: nil, digest: "9a10843635b9e9ad4241c96b90f4d331", downloads: 0, author_id: 1, created_on: "2014-03-07 17:37:50", description: "", disk_directory: "2014/03">, #<Attachment id: 74, container_id: 1, container_type: "Project", filename: "MainApp.cs", disk_filename: "140307233750_MainApp.cs", filesize: 1160, content_type: nil, digest: "6b985033e19c5a88bb5ac4e87ba4c4c2", downloads: 0, author_id: 1, created_on: "2014-03-07 17:37:50", description: "", disk_directory: "2014/03">]
```

I need to extract the value 73 and 74 from this string  which is Attachment id.

is there any way to extract this value

Comment: How are you getting this ?

Comment: it's a value returned by a redmine method. (attach_files)

Comment: To clarify the question, and stem further downvotes, I suggest you: 1. replace 'string' in the first sentence with 'array'; 2. delete 'from the string which is Attachment id'; and 3. in IRB, define the array as `a` and report the class retuned by `a.class`, which I expect will be `Attachment`.

Answer (score 2):

just in case author meant he has an actual `String` instance:

`string = '[#<Attachment id: 73, container_id: 1, container_type: "Project", filename: "Eumna.zip", disk_filename: "140307233750_Eumna.zip", filesize: 235303, content_type: nil, digest: "9a10843635b9e9ad4241c96b90f4d331", downloads: 0, author_id: 1, created_on: "2014-03-07 17:37:50", description: "", disk_directory: "2014/03">, #<Attachment id: 74, container_id: 1, container_type: "Project", filename: "MainApp.cs", disk_filename: "140307233750_MainApp.cs", filesize: 1160, content_type: nil, digest: "6b985033e19c5a88bb5ac4e87ba4c4c2", downloads: 0, author_id: 1, created_on: "2014-03-07 17:37:50", description: "", disk_directory: "2014/03">]'`

`string.scan(/\sid: (\d+)/).flatten`
=> ["73", "74"]

Answer (score 1):

Do as below using [`Array#collect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-collect):

```
array.collect(&:id)
```

In case it is a string use [`JSON::parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) to get the array back from the string first, then use `Array#collect` method as below :

```
require 'json'
array = JSON.parse(string)
array.collect(&:id)
```

Answer (score 1):

The elements of the array (I'll call it `a`) look like instances of the class `Attachment` (not strings).  You can confirm that by executing `e.class` in IRB, where `e` is any element `a` (e.g., `a.first`).  My assumption is correct if it returns `Attachment`.  The following assumes that is the case.

@Arup shows how to retrieve the values of the instance variable `@id` when it has an accessor (for reading):

```
a.map(&:id)
```

(aka `collect`).  You can see if @id has an accessor by executing

```
e.instance_methods(false)
```

for any element `e` of `a`.  This returns an array which contains all the instance methods defined for the class `Attachment`. (The argument `false` causes Ruby's built-in methods to be excluded.) If @id does not have an accessor, you will need to use [Object@instance_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get):

```
a.map { |e| e.instance_variable_get(:@id) }
```

(You could alternatively write the argument as a string: `"@id"`).

If

```
s = '[#<Attachment id: 73, container_id: 1,..]'
```

in fact a string, but you neglected to enclose it in (single) quotes, then you must execute

```
a = eval(s)
```

to convert it to an array of instances of `Attachment` before you can extract the values of `:@a`.

Hear that 'click'?  That was me starting my stop watch.  I want to see how long it will take for a comment to appear that scolds me for suggesting the use of (the much-maligned) `eval`.

Two suggestions: shorten code to the essentials and avoid the need for readers to scroll horizontally to read it.  Here, for example, you could have written this:

```
a = [#<Attachment id: 73, container_id: 1>, #<Attachment id: 74, container_id: 1>]
```

All the instance variables I've removed are irrelevant to the question.

If that had been too long to fit on one lines (without scrolling horizontally, write it as:

```
a = [#<Attachment id: 73, container_id: 1>,
     #<Attachment id: 74, container_id: 1>]
```

Lastly, being new to SO, have a look at this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/about).